# View doesn't render CSS and Javascript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i work on a ASP.net MVC project, Ihave a view that contains some parts from shared layouts, I have three shared layout views one of them contain CSS files, second one contain Java Script files and the third one contain HTML code, and I use `@RenderPage` to set them as a part of a view.

My view contain :

```
//html code
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_CssPage.cshtml")
//html code
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_LeftSideBar.cshtml")
//html code
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_JsPage.cshtml")
```

_CssPage.cshtml :

```css
  <!-- Favicon-->
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
<link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Waves Effect Css -->
<link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Animation Css -->
<link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Morris Chart Css-->
<link href="plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom Css -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
<link href="css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

_LeftSideBar.cshtml :

```html
     <!-- Left Sidebar -->
<aside id="leftsidebar" class="sidebar">
    <!-- User Info -->
    <div class="user-info">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/user.png" width="48" height="48" alt="User" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-transform:uppercase">@ViewBag.User_ID</div>
            <div class="email">@ViewBag.User_Type</div>
            <div class="btn-group user-helper-dropdown">
                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">group</i>Followers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i>Likes</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">input</i>Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #User Info -->
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/Authentication/Redirect_To_User_Space">
                    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- #Menu -->
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="legal">
        <div class="version">
            <b>Version: </b> 1.0.5
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #Footer -->
</aside>
<!-- #END# Left Sidebar -->
```

_JsPage.cshtml :

```js
        <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
@rende

<!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Select Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<!-- Slimscroll Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>

<!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/node-waves/waves.js"></script>

<!-- Jquery CountTo Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/jquery-countto/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/morrisjs/morris.js"></script>

<!-- ChartJs -->
<script src="plugins/chartjs/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- Flot Charts Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>

<!-- Sparkline Chart Plugin Js -->
<script src="plugins/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Js -->
<script src="js/admin.js"></script>
<script src="js/pages/index.js"></script>

<!-- Demo Js -->
<script src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

when i try to access to my view it's look like this

[image: This what the view look like when i try to access to it]

please any help ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Please check the browser console for errors, Right Click > Inspect Element > Go to Console tab.

Comment: firstly thanks for your respond bro, I use Microsoft Edge based on Chromium as my browser

Comment: what do you see on dev tools console tab?

Comment: I see this message 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' for all my css and js files

Comment: I see, can you check sources tab next.If you hover a certain item for a few seconds, it will show the url. Are the urls correct? are your views working before or it's your first time building this page?

Comment: this is the first time i built this page

Comment: We need to know the location of your css folders.  I.e. plugins and css.  Are they inside another folder.  If so what?  Maybe provide a screenshot of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Path of the CSS and JS files need to add `/` before the link.

Example :

the original path is

`<link href="plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

you need to add the `slash` before the link like that :

`<link href="/plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

hope this help you.